# Why does removing a directory first remove its subdirectories recursively?

Tags: filesystems, directory, rm, recursive

Why must deleting `dir1`, which contains `dir2`, which in turn contains `dir3`, be a "recursive" operation and not just "simple" (destroying `dir1` as-is, regardless of its contents)?

Comment: If you refer to the `rm` command, it does, by default, only delete files and leaves out directories. In order to delete a directory, whether it contains files or directories, both or nothing, the recursive option `-r` is required.

Comment: Each file and directory under `dir` has entries in the filesystem and each of these entries must be deleted so the process has to be recursive. Also, each entry has to be checked to see if you have permission to delete it so a simple `rm dir1` is not so simple.

Comment: @AlexG The command `rm -d dir1` will remove the directory if it is empty.

Comment: I see, thanks. So your explanation is the correct one.

Comment: Directories are like indices. Removing them wouldn't exactly unallocate the mapped data. File locks and permissions also has to be respected. It's simply the natural way regardless if filesystems might be able to allow it.

Comment: Your question is "why?". If the underlying problem is "how can I remove a directory quickly?" then the solution may be: plan ahead and create it as a separate filesystem. It's easy to destroy a filesystem, there is no need to remove its files one by one. A btrfs subvolume may also work.